# Ngx-table angular2 swimlane com compilation issue

Tags: angular, compilation, ngx-datatable

I am trying to use  [ngx-datatable](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/)  and after the installation I am getting compilation errors. I am searching the issue since last few hours and have no idea what is causing it.

- Installed it using the usual way : `npm install
  @swimlane/ngx-datatable`
- Imported the module in `app.module.ts`

`import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable`

```
 imports: [
    NgxDatatableModule,
    BrowserModule]
```

HTML :

```
<ngx-datatable
           class="material striped"
          [rows]="rows"
          [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/column-mode.type.d.ts
>   (2,16): In ambient enum  declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/column-mode.type.d.ts
>   (3,12): In ambient enum  declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/column-mode.type.d.ts
>   (4,13): In ambient enum  declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/sort.type.d.ts
>   (2,14): In ambient enum declar ations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/sort.type.d.ts
>   (3,13): In ambient enum declar ations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/sort-direction.type.d.ts
>   (2,11): In ambient e num declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/sort-direction.type.d.ts
>   (3,12): In ambient e num declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/selection.type.d.ts
>   (2,14): In ambient enum d eclarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/selection.type.d.ts
>   (3,13): In ambient enum d eclarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/selection.type.d.ts
>   (4,18): In ambient enum d eclarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/selection.type.d.ts
>   (5,12): In ambient enum d eclarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/selection.type.d.ts
>   (6,16): In ambient enum d eclarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/click.type.d.ts
>   (2,14): In ambient enum decla rations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/click.type.d.ts
>   (3,14): In ambient enum decla rations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/contextmenu.type.d.ts
>   (2,14): In ambient enum  declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.
>
> ERROR in
>   `my-package`/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/types/contextmenu.type.d.ts
>   (3,12): In ambient enum  declarations member initializer must be
>   constant expression.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the issue on their Github page: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/927

It seems that updating to Typescript 2.4 might solve the problem (it did for me). Of course, keep in mind that one should update it in npm and/or Visual Studio depending on the tools you're using.

Comment: Yup. I did the same. I got the link few minutes back. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

this answer solved my problem (I founded it in https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/927):

1. Open package.json and remove the line where you define typescript
   dependency and its version
2. Remove node_modules folder
3. Remove package-lock.json file (if you use NPM 5+)
4. Run npm install typescript@latest --save
5. Run npm install